# display image file name after choose file(web)

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I need to display the file name after choose the file from file input on a HTML page(`<input type=file>`).I am using Ruby on rails(Probably it doesn't matter).Pls give me some hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
var file_name = $(this).val();
});
```

check the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cGVCB/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ruby, but i'm shure you can use Javascript / jQuery:

```
alert($('#idOfYourUploadField').val());
```

Combine it with a change listener, or something, to get it on every change.